# Store several words in a session array and then show them

Tags: php

I'm writting a quiz. First the question is shown in question.php then in answer.php, the answer is analised, if the answer is right the word is stored in an array and if wrong in another. Then go back to question.php and so on. When there are no more questions, the result.php will show which words have been correct and which ones were wrong.

Please note that the session array needs to include a new word every time the answer.php is loaded.

EDIT: The problem is that the session array is only storing the first item

My code:

answer.php :

```
 <?php
 session_start();

 $question = $_GET['question'];
 $user_answer = $_GET['user_answer'];
 $right_answer = mysql_query("SELECT french FROM words where english='$question'");
 $fila = mysql_fetch_assoc($right_answer); 
 $fila_french = $fila['french'];

 if ( $user_answer == $fila_french ) { 
    echo "Right"; 
    $_SESSION['right_words'] = array();
    array_push($_SESSION['right_words'], $question);
     }

     else { echo "Wrong"; 
     $_SESSION['wrong_words'] = array();
    array_push($_SESSION['wrong_words'], $question);
     }
 echo "<a href='question.php' > Next </a>";
 ?>
```

result.php :

```
 <?php
 session_start();

 $right_answers = implode(',',$_SESSION['right_words']);
 $wrong_answers = implode(',',$_SESSION['wrong_words']);  

 echo "<h1> You finished the test </h1> 
 <p> You have these words right: $right_answers</p>
 <p> You have these words wrong: $wrong_answers</p>
 <a href='../exercises.php'> Go back to exercises </a>";
 ?>
```

Thanks for you help!

Comment: Do you mean [implode()](http://php.net/implode) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say what the problem is but you will only get 1 item in each array as in your if/else blocks you are assigning a new empty array to your session variables. You should check if these variables are already defined before doing this:

```
if (!$_SESSION['right_words']) { $_SESSION['right_words'] = array(); }
```

And do the same for 'wrong_words'.

For your result.php file, to list all of the answers separated by a comma you can use `implode`:

```
$right_answers = implode(',',$_SESSION['right_words']);
$wrong_answers = implode(',',$_SESSION['wrong_words']);
```

Comment: Problem is that the session array is only storing the first item

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know how to "check if these variables are already defined" :(

Comment: `if (!$_SESSION['right_words'])` (as per example in my answer) will return true if it is not defined.

Comment: but in theory array_push will include a new item in the array even if the array is already defined no?

Comment: Yes it will, that is not the problem. It is the assignment to `array()` which wipes out anything that was there previously and creates a new empty array. See lines 12 and 17 in your code.